# Bigquery - how is data distributed by partition key?

Tags: google-bigquery

I come from a Teradata and Netezza background in Data Warehousing in MPP technologies.

I would like to ask how Google BigQuery distributes data by partition key on a simple table? I am really trying to understand the logic in how the BigQuery engine works if this makes sense?

Teradata and Netezza had a well documented technical page from recollection which described the processes used (like a step by step walkthrough).

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery's partitioned tables are also very well documented here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

I think I don't understand what you want to know. Please rephrase your question after reading all the above.